# How to set listviews in horizontalScrollView to fill up the screen?

Tags: android, listview, horizontalscrollview

I have three listviews in horizontalScrollView. I want to make each of them to occupy the full screen, by including them into a linearlayout which is set to (layout_width: match_parent, layout_height: match_parent). However, it doesn't work. As you see from the screenshot, the three listviews just tightly linked with one another.

Any suggestions so that the three listviews each occupies the full screen? THx a lot.

[image]

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/page_bg_color">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ListView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tab_login_myFriends_requestList"
                android:background="#ffffffff" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ListView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tab_login_myFriends_pendingList"
                android:background="#ffffffff" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ListView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tab_login_myFriends_confirmedList"
                android:background="#ffffffff" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: what do you mean occupy the whole screen? you have 3 listviews? Do you want something like one next to the other? in equal proportion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this,

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#attr_android:fillViewport

Set that to true. Also your listviews should probably have a weight attribute associated with them.

But I can't really figure out what you're trying to do. Maybe provide the xml and I'll guide you further.

I think what you're looking for is this,

http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

Comment: @Derekyy have a look at my answer

Comment: yes, the screen slide is what I am loooking for. thx. reading it now.